# So what does /24 have to do with 255 in hosts IP addresses?

Tags: ip, ports

Quote:

> For example, 192.168.10.0/24 would scan the 256 hosts between
>   192.168.10.0 (binary: 11000000 10101000 00001010 00000000) and 192.168.10.255 (binary: 11000000 10101000 00001010 11111111)

[Source](https://nmap.org/book/man-target-specification.html).

I know 256 is 2 ^ 8 but I don't know what 24 have anything to do with 2 ^ 8? Anybody can enlighten me on this?

Comment: It means "use the 24 first bits (out of 32) as mask". And this has nothing to do with infosec

Comment: While technically interesting, I've edited your question since it is not actually related to nmap (and not related to IT Security either) but is just about IP addresses notation.

Comment: I'm not sure playing around with nmap is a good idea if you do not even know the basics of subnetting

Comment: And, BTW, the first and last addresses, 192.168.10.0 and 192.168.10.255, are **not** scanned: they are not addresses, they have a special meaning. The first indicates the whole subnet, the second is the broadcast address, *i.e.* an adress  which applies to all machines in the subnet.

Answer (score 6):

You almost provided the answer yourself. See the IP addresses in binary:

```
11000000 10101000 00001010 00000000
11000000 10101000 00001010 11111111
```

Notice how many bits are the same for the range of ip-addresses you are scanning. The answer is `24`. The `IP-address/X` is a way to specify a range of IP addresses. Simply put it means the range of IP addresses where the first `X` bits are the ones in the IP.

Thus:

```
127.0.0.0/24 specifies the range 127.0.0.0 - 127.0.0.255
127.0.0.0/20 specifies the range 127.0.0.0 - 127.0.15.255
127.0.0.0/16 specifies the range 127.0.0.0 - 127.0.255.255
```

and so forth.

[A nice online subnet calculator you can play with to understand things.](http://jodies.de/ipcalc)

Comment: In your second example the range should be 127.0.0.0-127.0.15.255

Answer (score 3):

As you have mentioned `192.168.10.0/24` specifies the range between `192.168.10.0` to `192.168.10.255`, `/24` specifies number of masked bits out of 32 starting from left. So, in binary `/24` would be represented as `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000` and it is called a mask since first 24 bits of all IP's in this range are going to be same.

How `/24` is useful is explained here:

Take an IP in the range, say `192.168.10.12` .When you apply a bitwise `And` operation on this ip and `/24` as follows

```
192.168.10.12 - 11000000 10101000 00001010 00001100
mask -/24     - 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000
result of &   - 11000000 10101000 00001010 00000000
```

you will get the result as `192.168.10.0` which is IP address of the network the host `192.168.10.12` belongs to. This is the way mask is helpful.

Comment: simply and clear. this is the best explained answer.

Answer (score 2):

An IPv4 address is composed of *32 bits*.

/24 means that the first **24 bits** define the network. So you have the remaining **8 bits** for the hosts.

*2^8* =256 addresses, as the first one defines the network and the last one is the broadcast, you have 254 effective addresses.

```
decimal  192       168      10       0
binary 11000000 10101000 00001010 00000000
mask   11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000  //24 bits are static and 8 bits are dynamic
```

Comment: This is about the clearest short answer I have ever seen to this question.  It would have saved me lots of head scratching back when I was learning all this.